# Is there a way to insert object into DB using node.js mssql module

Tags: sql-server, node.js, node-modules

I found a few examples to insert objects into DB directly by doing something like:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'cccc.net',
  user     : 'username',
  password : 'password',
});

var post  = {srcUserID: userSrcID, destUserID: msg.userid, messageContent: msg.txt, messageSendDate:sendDate };

connection.query('INSERT INTO messages SET ?', post, function(err, result) {

});
```

But this works with mysql module and I have SQL Server as my DB so I am using

```
var SQL_DB = require('mssql');
```

Is there a way to insert objects directly to DB in the same way how its possible with mysql module.

Answer (score 0):

looking at node-mssql v4 docs, they used this as an example using callbacks:

```
const sql = require('mssql');

const config = {
    user: '...',
    password: '...',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: '...',
    pool: {
        max: 10,
        min: 0,
        idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
    }
};

const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
const transaction = new sql.Transaction(pool);

transaction.begin(err => {
// ... error checks

    const request = new sql.Request(transaction)
    request.query('insert into mytable (mycolumn) values (12345)', (err, result) => {
    // ... error checks

        transaction.commit(err => {
            // ... error checks

            console.log("Transaction committed.")
        })
    })
})
```

EDIT: node-mssql seems to use request.input for escaping values but does not accept a js object, you could quickly make your own:

```
sql.connect(config, err => {

    var post = {
        srcUserID: userSrcID,
        destUserID: msg.userid,
        messageContent: msg.txt,
        messageSendDate: sendDate
    };

    const request = new sql.Request();

    let cols = [];
    let inputs = [];
    for (let k in post) {
        request.input(k, post[k]);
        cols.push(k);
        inputs.push('@' + k);
    }

    let query = `insert into messages (${cols.toString()}) values (${inputs.toString()})`;

    request.query(query, (err, result) => {
        //stuff here
    });

});
```

Comment: This is inserting records by specifying each column and respective value in the query. I wanted a way to insert the object and let library do the query construction.